# Did any indian philosopher try to address the omnipotent paradox?

Tags: philosophy

> Can [an omnipotent being] create a stone so heavy that it cannot lift it.[(*Source*)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotence_paradox)

So did an Indian philosopher or a hindu philosopher answer this question?

Or is there any answer to this question according to hindusim or hindu philosophy?

Comment: The question arises in Western theism, it does not arise in Vedanta. There is no 'creation' in Hinduism, there is projection - srishti. The 'paradox' only exists within the confines of maya, within circular reasoning of causal reasoning. In the super sensuous realm there are no paradoxes, no stones, no 'heavy'.

Comment: Please note that question is framed in very medieval terms, which are no longer relevant. As the link you gave mentions, when you talk of weight, you imply a gravitational field. If you keep increasing mass of stone and keep it at a reasonable volume, the stone will undergo gravitational collapse. Please come up with a more meaningful formulation of the problem.

Comment: @alsoran that's a good theory or answer.